# Neo4j auto startup on Windows Server 2012R2

Tags: database, windows, neo4j

I have a Windows Sever 2012 R2 Standard with neo4j installed. But every time I start up the server I have to manually start/run the database.

Is there an option to auto start a neo4j database when windows starts up?

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/windows/ I would say you can set up a service :

```
bin\neo4j install-service
```

Is that what you are looking for ?

Hope this helps !

Regards,
Tom